# MS Dynamics CRM: Is there way to check personal view against existing attributes?

Tags: dynamics-crm

If you want to remove some attributes from the entity, a check is made to see if they are used in global views. For personal views, a similar check is not performed, and if the user wants to use a personal view that contains a non-existent attribute, he will only see a not very explanatory error message.
Is there any way to check the use of non-existent attributes in a personal view?

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to do dependency check from an attribute to personal views. I don't see a XrmToolBox plugin to achieve the same.

Probably you can do some sdk calls to pull all the personal views and check the content in query FetchXml and layout xml for your attributes, and go from there.